# Arithmetic operation successful in C# - Throws exception in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

Code in C#:
    address = glowObject + (glowIndex * 0x38) + 0x4;
Code in VB:
    address = glowObject + (glowIndex * &H38) + &H4

I inserted a breakpoint on that line in both my C# code and VB code.
The values were the same in both.
C#: Breakpoint:
[image: C# Breakpoint]
VB Breakpoint:
[image: VB Breakpoint]
So it looks like my VB code is getting the result, but it's still throwing an exception on that line of code. 
[image: Exception]
What could be causing this?

Comment: That's entirely by design, it did overflow as the exception says.  Hard to guess how this expression could be correct, *glowIndex* look entirely too large.  Randomly, you could use CLng(address) to ensure the addition uses 64-bit math.

Comment: Tried converting it to a long/setting the variable type to a long aswell, still throwing the same exception :/

Comment: Yay, more CS hacks!

Comment: Yay :^) my C# version already works, trying to convert it to VB for a separate project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :)
It was as simple as checking a box in the compiler options.
Thank you to Thomas Levesque for telling me about the [compiler option.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07bysfz2.aspx)
[image: Solution]
Go to the compile tab in your project settings, click on Advanced Compiler Settings, and check the "Remove integer overflow checks"

Answer (score 4):

In C#, arithmetic operations are unchecked by default, which means that arithmetic overflow is not checked at runtime. You can control this with the [`checked`/`unchecked` keywords, and/or with the `/checked` compiler option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx).

In VB.NET, arithmetic operations are checked by default.

In your code, the result overflows the capacity of an `int`; in C#, it overflows silently, producing an incorrect result, whereas in VB.NET, it throws an exception. In either case, your code has a bug...

Comment: Well, it's not a fixable bug. It reads memory from an address in a game, and I have no control over those values, so I'm guessing the only way to fix this is make it unchecked in vb?

Comment: @JustinG, the C# code overflows and assigns a negative value to `address`. Are you saying that it successfully accesses memory at a negative address?!

Comment: Apparently. I'm not sure, it works flawlessly. It writes memory to that address successfully. Isn't the address 200033024?

Comment: Ah, I fixed it :D

Comment: @JustinG for me it's -1291426300, with the values from your screenshot